# Find online friends from ci_sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am implementing a chat system in codeigniter so now i want to display online friends. Now i want to know how to find count/name of friends that are online, I have a ci_sessions table in which i am storing session, codeigniter automatic store it u know about it. I have a table call friends in which i have list of my friends the structure of table is this

```
 id      user_id      friend_id
  1           1             2
  2           1             3
  3           1             4
```

like this. so i want to know online users from ci_session on the basis of friends table. so I used this in view or html

```
    <?php

        $this->db->where("user_data <>","");
        $query = $this->db->get('ci_sessions');
        $result=$query->result();

        foreach ($result as $row) 
        {
            $user_data=$row->user_data;
            foreach (unserialize($user_data) as $k => $v) 
            {
                // here is something will be done if i m not wrong 
            } 

        }


    ?>
```

suppose my all friends are online so how can i find their count/ name/ id . thanks.

Comment: does the table which store the ci_session has a column for the user id?

Comment: no it stores in user_data if we unserialize then we can get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this one by adding usir_id colum in ci_sessions table and then join this by this query, but first u should make your session library and little bit code will be changed in builit in session that can be found on system/library 
first you view this article to change that and u will get idea how to do this 
[Find Online Friends using ci_sessions](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/207643/)

then use this code for fetching data. i used it in my view. you can use it as you want.

```
    $data = array();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_sessions');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id=ci_sessions.user_id');
    $this->db->join('friends', 'friends.user_id=ci_sessions.user_id or friends.sender_id=ci_sessions.user_id');

     $this->db->where('ci_sessions.user_id !=', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->where('friends.sender_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->or_where('friends.user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->where('users.user_id !=' , $this->session->userdata('user_id'));

    $this->db->where('friends.status', 1);

    $this->db->where('user_data !=', '');


    $query = $this->db->get();
    $num_rows   =   $query->num_rows();
```

and then use this to display friends name, u can change as u want.

```
                <?php 

            if ($num_rows <= 0){?> 

             foreach ($query->result() as $row)
             {
                $udata = unserialize($row->user_data);
                /* put data in array using username as key */
                $data[$udata['name']] = $udata['name'];

                $time=$row->last_activity;
                $timeOut = time() -  150; 

                if ($time >= $timeOut)
                { //display name} else
                      echo $data[$udata['name']];

               }

        }} ?>
```

Comment: I spent a lot of time to find this type to the point solution. thanks @Aysha Ali...

Answer (score 1):

Something *like*

```
SELECT 
   user.name 
FROM users 
WHERE user_ID IN(SELECT friend_ID FROM friends WHERE user_ID='$current_user') AND
      user_ID IN(SELECT user_ID FROM ci_sessions)`
```

Should work.

Then use `$db->num_rows;` for the count.

**UPDATE**

This runs every time the user object is created:

```
UPDATE users SET last_activity=NOW() WHERE entity_ID=?
```

Then the query to use this:

```
SELECT 
    entities.UUID, 
    users.entity_ID, users.first_name, users.last_name, userinfo.image_ID 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN entities ON entities.ID=users.entity_ID 
LEFT JOIN friends ON users.entity_ID=friends.user_ID_1 OR 
                     users.entity_ID=friends.user_ID_2 
LEFT JOIN userinfo ON users.entity_ID=userinfo.user_ID
WHERE 
    (friends.user_ID_1=? OR friends.user_ID_2=?) AND friends.approved=1 AND 
    users.entity_ID!=? AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, users.last_activity, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 15) 
ORDER BY first_name DESC
```

Comment: there is no column for user_id in ci_sessions

Comment: Then either unserialize it and use it in the query or modify code or do it in another way (I'll post 'my way' in my answer).